# Getting token from the URL in Java

Tags: java, security, url, authentication

In my project requirement, I was given a URL http://abc.grp.auth where it is accessible only in **abc network**. Am hitting this URL from browser and able to view the token in below format.

```
{"token" : "eqwqkldsdkldflanflna$%$!@#"}
```

I want to get this token in java code within abc network as below.

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```

But this code is giving 401 exception. This URL is taking the windows login, validating and sending the token. How can I achieve this in Java.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Browser might be using SSO

Comment: pls provide some examples for single sign on. I saw this https://cuit.columbia.edu/cas-ify-java-application. How to use this?

Comment: If it is CAS, check this example https://github.com/UniconLabs/cas-sample-java-webapp

Comment: Import as a eclipse maven project or just build using maven. If maven console: Go to the root directory. Run `mvn clean package`. Go to the `target` directory and get the `cas-sample-java-webapp.war`. Put the WAR file into a servlet container such as Tomcat. Connect to the web app, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If there is used some kind of Basic authentication you can  try to set special request header. Like this:

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
String encoding = Base64.encode(usr + ":" + psw);
httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
```